# What is the maximum number of riders for a dragon in “Game of Thrones?”

Tags: game-of-thrones, house-of-the-dragon

In the *Game of Thrones* series, as well as in the "Dance of the Dragons" in the *House of the Dragon* (2022) series, there are several instances where dragons play a pivotal role. One such instance is when Jon Snow rides one of Daenerys Targaryen's dragons.

How many riders can a dragon have in *Game of Thrones*? Is there a limit to the number of individuals a dragon can bond with or allow to ride it? This question also extends to the broader narrative of the *House of the Dragon* series, where dragons are prominently featured.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any indication that is more than 1

Comment: @Luciano - The source books differ with that view

Answer (score 3):

According to [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragonrider#:%7E:text=However%2C%20dragons%20are%20willing%20to,current%20rider%2C%20Prince%20Aemond%20Targaryen.), there is only one rider at a time, but it is possible that a dragonrider can bring along a guest with them and/or that a dragon may take on/bond with more than one dragonrider in their lifetime, if previous riders have died.

> A person may become a dragonrider at any age, much like horses and
> their riders; some when they are very young, some as teenagers, some
> not until adulthood. **Too ride a dragon, a person has to bond with the
> dragon. Once the dragon and the rider have bonded, that dragon will
> not allow anyone else to mount it alone while its rider lives, no
> matter how familiar said person might be to the dragon**. For example,
> when Rhaenyra Targaryen's son Joffrey Velaryon attempted to mount her
> dragon Syrax, Syrax shrugged him off mid-flight, causing him to fall
> to his death. **However, dragons are willing to accept another person
> upon their backs as long their own rider has also mounted. Queen
> Visenya Targaryen gave a ride to young Lord Ronnel Arryn upon her
> dragon Vhagar. A century later, Vhagar allowed Alys Rivers to ride
> behind her current rider, Prince Aemond Targaryen**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the end of S07E06, where Danny flies four passengers - Beric, Jorah, Tormund and Sandor:

[image]

So five at least :)